# How to pre-populate relational data (e.g. RealmList<Object>) into Realm

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

Is it possible to import relational data into Realm? My data model for ObjectA has a one-to-many relationship using List.

I pre-populated data using Realm Studio's import from CSV. Most of my data model is made up of Strings and Ints. But I'm not sure how to represent a List<> datatype in CSV.

As a workaround, I'll have my app populate the Realm with objects at runtime. But this approach uses one-time code, and this strikes me as basic functionality. There has to be a better way!

My data model:

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = "" 
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
}

class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    var owner = List<Person>()
}
```

Comment: Here on SO, we are looking for questions about specific coding issues - asking if it's possible it kinda vague. Do you have some code and example data we can take a look at to understand the issue? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update the question with details and some code we'll take a look.

Comment: Appreciate the pointers. I updated the question with more specifics, including a code sample for my data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read in ‘relational data’ you could write an app to read that data, populate your realm objects and save it to realm.

Representing relational data in a flat file usually has some common keys that associate that data. For example people and dogs. The people file may look like this; persons id, name and favorite food

```
1234,jay,pizza
5678,cindy,steak
```

then the dogs file would look like this with the dog id, dog name and then the persons (owners) id

```
1111,rover,1234
2222,spot,1234
3333,scraps,5678
```

In the above example, jay owns rover and spot and cindy owns scraps.

The realm PersonClass object would be

```
class PersonClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var person_id = ""
   @objc dynamic var person_name = ""
   @objc dynamic var fav_food = ""
   let dogList = List<DogClass>()
}
```

and then for the dogs

```
class DogClass: Object {
   @objc dynamic var dog_id = ""
   @objc dynamic var dog_name = ""
   @objc dynamic var person_id = ""
}
```

The process would be to read in the people (creating the people objects), read in the dogs, iterate over each dog and add it to that persons dogList - the person could be found by its person_id.

Ideally, it would best to include primary_keys with this structure.

Likewise, you could read all dogs and people into Realm Studio and the add the dogs to their respective people's dogList as well.

You can command-click on filenames to import multiple files into Realm Studio